# Modeling the causal impact of insurance benefits on customer satisfaction

Tags: self-study, causality, dag, deterministic

Consider the following scenario:

A health insurance company offers a few dozen different health insurance plans.

Within each plan there are many benefits which can take on different values, such as different copays, different network providers, different medical vendors, etc.

Every year, members in each plan rate their satisfaction with their plan.

The company wants to determine the causal impact of some benefit of interest on member satisfaction. For example, they want to know how the copay for an emergency room visit impacts member satisfaction.

You believe that it is reasonable to assume that plan has some direct impact on satisfaction as well. This is because different plans are offered in different locations and appeal to different types of people.

The complication is that benefits within a plan are always identical. Since the benefit values are a deterministic function of plan, if you stratify by plan, there is no variation among any benefit. For the same reason, if you treat plan as a cluster, there is no variation within the cluster. On the other hand, if you ignore plan, then the benefits are highly multicollinear since they're bundled together within the uncontrolled-for plans, and you also are no longer adjusting for the direct impacts of plan on satisfaction, which almost certainly exist and may be substantial.

If your dataset only includes the above mentioned data--the plans, the benefits, and the satisfaction for each member--is there any sound way to solve the company's problem? Why or why not?

Comment: Is this a self-study question? If so, please add the self-study tag. What DAG do you think models this scenario?

Comment: It is not homework, but I suppose it could be considered a self-study question, as it's a version of something I actually encountered. I had colleagues insisting that we could perform a regression of satisfaction on benefits and deal with multicollinearity by just adding/removing/transforming until the coefficient directions made sense (they came from a machine learning perspective). I futilely claimed that such a method would only provide false confidence without giving a trustworthy answer to the question of causality, and that we probably couldn't solve this problem with the data at hand.

Comment: The DAG I'm thinking of has the node "plan", "target benefit", "satisfaction", and other nodes for other benefits. Plan has an edge going out to all other nodes. All benefit nodes have an edge going out to satisfaction. If all of the functional relationships were probabilistic, this would be fairly simple, but the deterministic relationship between plan and benefits throws me off, and my hunch is that it makes this unsolvable. I have not worked with deterministic DAGs.

Comment: I think I would agree with you: plan completely determines benefits, and is a confounder of $\text{benefit}\to\text{satisfaction}.$ If adjusting for plan eliminates all variation in benefits, what's really going on is that plan and benefits almost are the same variable. At least, benefits isn't giving you any information that plan doesn't already. Maybe the right business question is this: which plan is providing the most satisfaction? Then, if you want to play around with offering plans with differing benefits, this approach might work.

Comment: That plan and benefit are almost the same variable is probably true. In a DAG, this would probably be better written in plate notation with plans as the plate instead of being a node. In such a case, all benefits within each plate are constant, and only the satisfaction varies. The issue is that when there are billions of dollars on the line and no decision makers understand either the logic or math underpinning these questions, nobody is willing to play around, but everybody wants "a model."

Comment: I think the best solution is to select a small subset of benefits that are suspected to have large impacts, then come up with a study design and collect data specifically for those variables that more directly addresses the question. I've tried for months to see if there is something I've missed that would allow me to make a model with the existing observations, but I can't come up with anything.

Comment: That sounds good to me!